# Brackets in BibLaTeX automatically

Tags: biblatex

Is it somehow possible to LaTeX automatically post the cite in brackets? So I don't need to create brackets around the \cite{}?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, danish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{kilder.bib}

\begin{document}
(\cite{<data>})
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I present your new best friend? `\parencite{}`!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=mla,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sarfraz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]